# Update and saving XML file changes its content to unrecognized characters in UWP

Tags: xml, uwp, xml-parsing, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to update "StanderdStyles.xaml" in UWP styles folder. When I do open and save the content of the file, it changes to unrecognized characters.

**Org doc:**

```
<!--  Non-brush values that vary across themes  -->

<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <x:String x:Key="BackButtonGlyph">&#xE071;</x:String>
        <x:String x:Key="BackButtonSnappedGlyph">&#xE0BA;</x:String>
```

**Updated xml:**

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <!--  Non-brush values that vary across themes  -->
  <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
      <x:String x:Key="BackButtonGlyph"></x:String>
      <x:String x:Key="BackButtonSnappedGlyph"></x:String>
      <!--  Removes the background transparency of textboxes  -->
      <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinHeight">32</x:Double>
      <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinWidth">64</x:Double>
      <x:Double x:Key="TextControlBackgroundRestOpacity">1</x:Double>
```

Code I use to update is as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.Load(rmModel.SourceCodePath + "\\Assets\\Styles\\StandardStyles.xaml");
var documentElement = doc1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1];
var defTheme = documentElement.ChildNodes[0];
var styles = defTheme.ChildNodes;

foreach (XmlNode item in styles)
{
  if (item.Attributes == null) continue;
  XmlAttribute idAttribute = item.Attributes["x:Key"];
  if (idAttribute != null && idAttribute.Value.Equals("FgBlue1_"))
  {
    item.InnerText = TextBoxColorCode.Text.Trim();
  }
}
doc1.Save(rmModel.SourceCodePath + "\\Assets\\Styles\\StandardStyles.xaml");
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio's text editor, the display of text depends on the font.

As you can see from the examples you gave, the text you added is not within the font support that the editor uses.

For example, your text editor font is `Arial`, but **Glyph**'s font is `Segoe MDL2 Assets`. Since the Unicode of Glyph's corresponding characters is not in the range supported by Arial, it cannot be parsed.

This is normal, if you need to display text, please change your editor font.

Best regards.

Comment: Before and after I update the XAML doc I open it with NotePad++. Is there anything I can do from code to prevent this from happening? As you can see I also lose the spaces I put between lines. :(

Comment: In addition to changing fonts, there is no other way to display special text. In addition, the spaces of the line only affect the typesetting, but the reading of the content does not affect. Visual Studio automatically adjusts the layout based on the current document format, but Notepad++ may need to do this with a plugin.